# Whats the difference between Jetpack Compose and the normal design Tool in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

Im new to Android Studio and i started learning it with YouTube Tutorials.

In all of these Tutorials i had to build the UI of the App via the Design Tool and the "activity_main.xml" provided by Android Studio.

But then i discovered that android had a full beginners cours on their website, so i started doing these. But in these Courses they use "State" and "Jetpack Compose" to build the UI.

Im confused on what to use ? Or maybe i missunderstood the whole purpose of both possibilitys ?

***When do i use Jetpack Compose and when shall i use the Design tool ?***

The Android Course im currently doing is: https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-3#codelab-https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-calculate-tip

I hope anyone can help me solve my problem, which pobably is just a missunderstanding from me though.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I give you a few definitions regarding your tags you threw in.

**Android Jetpack** it is a toolset which provides you valuable things like a database (in example room) and many more things. Check out  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/getting-started

**Compose** is kind of a successor of the well known xml-ui. I would suggest you to learn more about compose and try to build your UI using the "newer" toolset. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial

**XML** as stated above is a description of how your UI looks like. You basically chose your favorite layout and place objects on it. You already have found out about many available objects that the android-framework provides you out of the box (like a TextBox). Anyways, most layouts and objects are also available in Compose. If you like to learn more about the xml-layouts: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout

**State** - I'm not sure if I get you right here, but I guess you mean a UI-State. Usually you do not collect data from external repositories and hand it through your App and display it directly inside your UI. You should make use of at least a rough set software-architecture principles. This will include that you abstract your data (coming from ext. source) and form a so called ui-state for it. The UI-State is optimized for your representation inside your UI-Fragments. You can read more about the principles and best practices on https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders

**Regarding your question**

> When do i use Jetpack Compose and when shall i use the Design tool ?

You are free to use either compose, or xml as your UI-Description language (you also may mix up both, but I would not recommend it unless you have to transfer older apps).
While the xml-ui is available since the beginning of android, compose is about 2 years young. Both are provided with a design tool but I would suggest you to give the Compose-Toolchain a try.
There is a state-of-the-art previewer coming along with.
To find out more: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling

best regards